# Using asyncio with tkinter and it's ttk.progressbar widget: how to force an asyncio task to end?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, python-asyncio

Below is my script on using `asyncio` to operate with `tkinter` and its `ttk.Progressbar()` widget. I derived it after referring to these references ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33ecpl/neat_discovery_how_to_combine_asyncio_and_tkinter/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896365), [3](https://bugs.python.org/issue27546), [4](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), [5](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html)). I got the progessbar widget to work. But I can't seem to be able to cancel(stop) the `asyncio` Task object responsible for updating `tkinter.Tk()` that I have created to replace the usual `Tk()` event `mainloop()`. As such, I dont' see a command prompt or `>>>` prompt after the Tk() window is destroyed. **How can I or should I terminate the task object `root.update_task`?** I am using python 3.6. I was hoping `loop.shutdown_asyncgens()` could end the cancelled task but it did not. **Why did it not work?** Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox

import time
import asyncio

INTERVAL = 0.05 #seconds

class App(ttk.Frame):


    def __init__( self, master, loop, interval=0.05, *args, **kw ):
        super().__init__( master,style='App.TFrame')
        self.master = master
        self.loop = loop
        self._set_style()
        self._create_widgets()


    def _set_style( self ):
        print( '\ndef _set_style( self ):' )
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure( 'App.TFrame',  background='pink')
        self.style.configure( 'sp.TFrame',  background='light green')


    def _create_widgets( self ):
        print( '\ndef _create_widgets( self ):' )
        self.sp_frame = ttk.Frame( self, style='sp.TFrame' )
        self.sp_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #sp_frame widgets
        self.sp_label1 = ttk.Label( self.sp_frame, text='SP(s):')
        self.sp_combox = ttk.Combobox(
            self.sp_frame, state="readonly", values=['a','b','c']  )
        self.sp_combox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self._connect_esp)
        self.sp_pbar = ttk.Progressbar( self.sp_frame, length=200,
                                        mode='indeterminate',
                                        orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, )
        self.sp_label1.grid( row=0, column=0 )
        self.sp_combox.grid( row=0, column=1, padx=[10,0] )
        self.sp_pbar.grid(   row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew' )


    def _connect_esp( self, event):
        print( '\ndef connect_esp( self, event ):' )

        async def dojob( loop, start_time, duration=1 ):
            print( '\nasync def dojob( loop, end_time):' )
            while True:
                duration = 5 #seconds
                t = loop.time()
                delta = t - start_time
                print( 'wait time = {}'.format( delta ) )
                if delta >= duration:
                    break
                await asyncio.sleep( 1 )
            return True

        async def trackjob( loop ):
            print( '\nasync def trackjob( loop ):' )
            print( 'Job: STARTED' ) 
            start_time = loop.time()
            self.sp_pbar.start( 50 )
            self.sp_pbar.update_idletasks()

            result = await dojob( loop, start_time )
            print( 'result = ', result, type(result) )

            if result:
                self.sp_pbar.stop()
                self.sp_pbar.update_idletasks()
                print( 'Job: ENDED' ) 
                return True
            return False

        try:
            future = self.loop.create_task( trackjob( self.loop ) )
            print( 'future = ', future, type(future))
        except syncio.CancelledError as err:
            print( '_connect_esp(): future is cancelled.' )
            raise
        except asyncio.InvalidStateError as err:
            print( '_connect_esp(): The operation is not allowed in this state..' )
            raise
        except asyncio.TimeoutError as err:
            print( '_connect_esp(): The operation exceeded the given deadline..' )
            raise
        except Exception:
            raise


async def tk_update( root, interval=INTERVAL ):
    print( '\nasync def tk_update( interval ):' )
    try:
        while True:
            root.update() #tk update 
            await asyncio.sleep( interval )
    except tk.TclError as err:
        print( '\nasync def tk_update( self, interval ):' )
        if "application has been destroyed" not in err.args[0]:
            raise
    except asyncio.CancelledError as err:
        print( '\nasync def tk_update( self, interval ):' )
        print('Request to cancel tk_update_task received but may not be done.')
        await asyncio.sleep( interval )
    print( '\nasync def tk_update( interval ):' )
    print( '0 Cancelled = ', root.update_task.cancelled() )
    print('END of def tk_update')


def ask_quit( root, interval=INTERVAL ):
    '''Confirmation to quit application.'''
    print( '\ndef ask_quit( self ):' )
    task=root.update_task
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel( "Quit","Quit?" ):
        task.cancel()
        print( '1 Cancelled = ', task.cancelled() )
        root.destroy() #Destroy the Tk Window instance.
    print( '2 Cancelled = ', task.cancelled() )


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('300x100+0+24')
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.update_task = loop.create_task( tk_update( root ) ) 

    app = App( root, loop )
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    #root.mainloop() #DO NOT IMPLEMENT; this is replaced by running
                     # tk's update() method in a asyncio loop called loop.
                     # See tk_update() method and root.update_task.

    #Tell Tk window instance what to do before it is destroyed.
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
                  lambda :ask_quit( root ) ) 

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
        print('after loop.run_forever()')
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete( loop.shutdown_asyncgens() )
        loop.close()
    print( 'Is Loop closed = ', loop.isclosed() )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: My corrected script is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921428/5722359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use run_until_complete and when you cancel the task you'll drop out of the function. You were using run_forever and not stopping the loop so you never got past that function.

```
    loop.run_until_complete(root.update_task)
    #loop.run_forever()
```

Also see the doc for run_forever

```
loop.run_forever()
    Run the event loop until stop() is called.
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the need for `loop.stop()` to end a `run_forever` loop; I had wrongly thought that only `loop.close()` was needed. I have implemented `loop.stop()` at the end of my `.ask_quit()` method while still using `loop.run_forever()`. This was actually demonstrated in documentation's [hello world example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#hello-world-with-call-soon). However, I overlooked the use of the `.stop()` method there.

Comment: From this encounter, I learnt that **both** `loop.run_forever()` and `loop.run_until_complete(root.update_task)` **can be used to implement `tkinter.Tk()`'s event loop**. The latter worked as you had explained despite the asyncio task `root.update_task.cancelled=False` after `root.update_task.cancel()` was issued. An interesting discovery about using the `loop.run_forever()` approach, after further testing with my script,  is that the asyncio loop can be stopped and cancelled w/o even bothering to first cancel the asyncio task `root.update_task`.

Comment: @Craftables I discovered that when the progressbar is running and the tkinter application is manually exited, a `RunTimeError` exception can occur for  a `run_until_complete` event loop while a `run_forever` event loop would not have this issue and the application can exit cleanly. The `run_forever` event loop may be simpler to implement tkinter.Tk()'s event loop. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921428/5722359) to my other related question here.